# How to display message about maximum file size restriction in RichFaces 4 fileUpload component

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have implemented a file upload using RichFaces 4.3. File upload works fine, alert about file types works fine, but alert about max file size restriction doesn't. File upload code:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="bannerUpload"
    fileUploadListener="#{bean.bannerListener}"
    acceptedTypes="png, gif, jpg, jpeg"
    ontyperejected="alert('#{msg.bannerFormatRestriction}');"
    maxFilesQuantity="1"
    sizeExceededLabel="File size is restricted. Max allowed size is 1 MB."
    serverErrorLabel="File was not uploaded. Please try again."
    addLabel="Select image for banner">
</rich:fileUpload>
```

Context parameters are set up and restriction works. But alert message is not displayed. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Problem with message is related to `fileupload.js.jsf line 213`.
 Error message in Firebug: `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: ...?rf_fu_uid=... does not permit framing.` and `Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'   var contentDocument = event.target.contentWindow.document`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mechanism to show the faces messages generated by the `fileUpload`, e.g.:

```
<rich:message for="bannerUpload" showDetail="true" ajaxRendered="true"/>
```

**UPDATE**

According to the error text `"Load denied by X-Frame-Options: ...?rf_fu_uid=... does not permit framing."`, to me it looks like there are two possible causes:

1. `X-Frame-Options` header has the value `DENY`. Change it to `SAMEORIGIN` to allow framing for your site.
2. `X-Frame-Options` header has the value `SAMEORIGIN`, but for some reason fileUpload tries to put into a frame something from different domain.

Both can be checked on the Network tab of Firebug.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Message about restriction is displayed inside fileUpload component and is not related to rich:message or rich:messages. I have tested it (with rich:message and rich:messages) before question was posted. In my case problem with message is related to fileupload.js.jsf line 213. Firebug display: "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: ...?rf_fu_uid=... does not permit framing." and "Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'" "var contentDocument = event.target.contentWindow.document".

Comment: @VasilLukach I have updated my answer based on firebug log you provided.

Comment: After removing X-FRAME-OPTIONS all messages are displayed properly. Thanks Andrey.

Comment: You are welcome Vasil, if the header was set for security reasons, setting it's value to SAMEORIGIN should be enough for rich:fileUpload.