# File upload event does not complete for rich:fileUpload (RichFaces 4.3.3.FINAL)

Tags: file-upload, progress-bar, richfaces

I am facing issues with rich:fileUpload component of RichFaces 4.3.3.FINAL. File upload event does not complete.

File gets successfully. I can read the data in excel without any issues. But it seems **onuploadcomplete does not work after that**. Even the progress popup does not stop after upload completes. Users will not know whether the file is successfully uploaded or not.

---

```
    <rich:fileUpload id="excelUpload"
    fileUploadListener="#{bulkUploadUIController.excelFileUploadListener}" 
    acceptedTypes=".xls" maxFilesQuantity="1" serverErrorLabel="File Upload Failed" onuploadcomplete="alert('Uploaded Completed !')" 
noDuplicate="true" 
listHeight="100px" 
ontyperejected="Invalid file type selected !" />
```

---

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't have `onuploadcomplete` in it. Any errors in the console?

Comment: I removed that as it was not working anyway. But I will edit my post above so that it will not create any confusion.

Comment: No errors then? You can try using a newer version of RichFaces, if there was a bug it might have been fixed.

Comment: I had similar problem when X-FRAME-OPTIONS was set (to DENY for example). Check it too. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292425/how-to-display-message-about-maximum-file-size-restriction-in-richfaces-4-fileup).

Comment: Thanks. I think X-FRAME-OPTIONS is enabled for my application. I will check this out.

Comment: Thanks a ton. The issue is resolved. X-FRAME-OPTIONS is set to same origin and it worked. It was set to DENY.

Comment: This worked. Great. Thanks a lot !!!